How do i get rid of this error in my .module.css file?
i have this magento + pwa studios + tailwind project where we write css in a .module.css file like this:
.price {
    composes: my-5 from global;
    composes: text-[0.9rem] from global;
}

this code works but there is a red squiggly line below [0.9rem] saying

"] expectedcss(css-lbracketexpected)"

we have a .eslintrc.js file where we add eslint exceptions like this:
const config = {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    extends: ['@magento'],
    rules: {
        'no-prototype-builtins': 'off',
        'no-undef': 'off',
        'no-useless-escape': 'off',
    }
};

module.exports = config;

i can't find the correct rule to turn off to get rid of that red line, can anyone help?
i tried adding 'css-lbracketexpected': 'off', in the rules object but the error won't go away.
i don't know what else to try as i can't find anything else online.
